# SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 - Error in devops pipeline Could not deploy package

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-sql-database, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to deploy dacpac to an existing sql db, and getting the following error:

##[error]*** Could not deploy package.
##[error]Unable to connect to target server 'AAA.database.windows.net'. Please verify the connection information such as the server name, login credentials, and firewall rules for the target server.
Cannot open server
##[error] 'MyMSSQlServer' requested by the login. Client is not allowed to access the server.

##[error]The Azure SQL DACPAC task failed. SqlPackage.exe exited with code 1.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-

Here are my steps in release pipeline:

```
- download: current
  artifact: databases

- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: Execute Azure SQL Dacpac
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MySuvscription'
    ServerName: 'MyMSSQlServer.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'AAA'
    SqlUserName: 'mysqlserveradmin'
    SqlPassword: 'mysqlserverpassword'
    DacpacFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\databases\foldera\folderb\folderc\folderd\MyApp.Database.dacpac'
    IpDetectionMethod: AutoDetect
```

I assumed IpDetectionMethod should handle the access permission. Can anyone suggest how to fix this now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- download: current
  artifact: databases

- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: Execute Azure SQL Dacpac
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MySubscription'
    ServerName: 'MyMSSQlServer.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'AAA'
    SqlUserName: 'mysqlserveradmin'
    SqlPassword: 'mysqlserverpassword'
    deployType: 'DacpacTask'
    DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
    DacpacFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\databases\foldera\folderb\folderc\folderd\MyApp.Database.dacpac'
    AdditionalArguments: //If you have any parameters, sql cmd variables please add here
    IpDetectionMethod: 'IPAddressRange'
    StartIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
    EndIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
    DeleteFirewallRule: true
```

Comment: I am really glad you finally make it work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate all the help, I am learning and getting into IaC and Yaml deployments and the support is very encouraging.

Comment: IaaC (Ansible, Terraform, etc), Containers, DevOps are all complementary. Enjoy the ride

Answer (score 1):

The error message is showing the Database name where the Server name should be:
Unable to connect to target server 'AAA.database.windows.net' instead of 'MyMSSQlServer.database.windows.net'.

Check if these parameters were entered correctly.

Comment: Sorry since I was masking the names I did not do it properly but the parameters are all correct, thank you for your observation :) My apologies @Carlos Ataide and all others who might have got confused

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have set the Azure SQL Firewall to allow Azure Services access to the database.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Couple of things I tried were adding 0.0.0.0 as start and end ips which basically resulted in a different error which is: "A project which specifies SQL server 2019 or Azure SQL Database Managed ***nstance as the target platform cannot be published to Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12"

Comment: I found out that a suggested fix for this issue is to update sqlproj file in below line: <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP> Basically introduce V12 but now my sql project is not building. So I am thinking of changing the sqlproj file to sdk style

Comment: I am not sure now if this issues should be closed or how should I proceed please let me know? Anyone? Thanks for all your help! Thanks Alberto for suggestion :)

Comment: Yes Allow Azure services check was enabled

Comment: Trying to think what else could be the reason because usually is a firewall issue.

Comment: - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: Execute Azure SQL Dacpac
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MySub'
    ServerName: 'svrname.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'AAA'
    SqlUserName: 'uname'
    SqlPassword: 'pwd'
   deployType: 'DacpacTask'
   DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
   DacpacFile: '$(PipelineWorkspace)\databases\folder1\MyProject.Database.dacpac'
   AdditionalArguments: //If you have any parameters, sql cmd variables please add here
   IpDetectionMethod: 'IPAddressRange'
   StartIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
   EndIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
  DeleteFirewallRule: true

Comment: This worked for me @Alberto Morillo, I will post as answer as well